# Xamarin forms: Layout visibility show/hide not working in iOS but working in Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a list containing two stack layout. Upon clicking the first stack in need to show/hide the second stack. This is working perfectly in android, but is not working in iOS. layout is not expanding when IsVisible is true.

```
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PackageList}"
                              ItemSelected="Package_ItemSelected"
                              IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
                              HasUnevenRows="True" 
                              SeparatorVisibility="None">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Padding="10" Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="10" BackgroundColor="#f2f2f2">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Item.PackageType}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                        <StackLayout Spacing="5" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Item.PackageName}" Style="{DynamicResource LabelStyle}" YAlign="Center"/>
                            <Label Text="(can accept/decline request only)" IsVisible="{Binding Item.PackageType}" Style="{DynamicResource LabelGraySmall}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" YAlign="Center"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <Grid HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" >
                            <Image Source="up.png" Style="{DynamicResource ArrowStyle}" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                            <Image Source="downsmall.png" Style="{DynamicResource ArrowStyle}" IsVisible="{Binding IsNotVisible}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Padding="15" Spacing="10" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}">
                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Item.Description}" Style="{DynamicResource LabelStyle}" YAlign="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                        <Button Text="Choose Package" Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.PackageCommand,Source={x:Reference packagePage}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Item}" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonBlue}" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

backend code

```
  private void Package_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {

            if (e.SelectedItem == null) return;
            if (e.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                var tappedItem = (PackageWrapper<PackageResult>)e.SelectedItem;
                tappedItem.IsNotVisible = !tappedItem.IsNotVisible;
                tappedItem.IsVisible = !tappedItem.IsNotVisible;
            }
        ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
    }
```

Wrapper class:

```
    public class PackageWrapper<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public T Item { get; set; }
    bool isVisible =  false;
    public bool IsVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return isVisible;
        }
        set
        {
            if (isVisible != value)
            {
                isVisible = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsVisible"));
            }
        }
    }
    bool isNotVisible = true;
    public bool IsNotVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return isNotVisible;
        }
        set
        {
            if (isNotVisible != value)
            {
                isNotVisible = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsNotVisible"));
            }
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
}
```

Please refer the screenshot for details

**Below is what i am getting in iOS**

[image: Below is what i am getting in iOS]

**Below is the expectation as in android.**
[image]

Comment: please put your code because using IsVisible it's working fine in both ios and android, i think some problem in code.

Comment: @Pratik updated with code

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on iOS.

You need to call Cell.ForceUpdateSize to get iOS to resize the cell.

You should be able to do this in your code behind. Something like:

```
var tappedItem = (PackageWrapper<PackageResult>)e.SelectedItem;
tappedItem.IsNotVisible = !tappedItem.IsNotVisible;
tappedItem.IsVisible = !tappedItem.IsNotVisible;

var viewCell = tappedItem.Parent.Parent as ViewCell;
viewCell.ForceUpdateSize();
```

I notice that you are only calling that code if the OS is Android. Any reason for this?

Be aware that this is expensive in terms of processing and might slow things down.

[Have a look at this example](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UserInterface/ListView/DynamicUnevenListCells) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i am calling it only in android due to this issue in IOS. As a workaround i set all cells visible in iOS. The solution doesn't seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Update your backend code remove Device.RuntimePlatform==Device.Android condition

```
     private void Package_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {

                if (e.SelectedItem == null) return;
                if (e.SelectedItem != null)
                {
                    var tappedItem = (PackageWrapper<PackageResult>)e.SelectedItem;
                    // ViewModel.PackageList.remove(tappedItem);
tappedItem.IsNotVisible = !tappedItem.IsNotVisible;
                    tappedItem.IsVisible = !tappedItem.IsNotVisible;
                    //ViewModel.PackageList.Add(tappedItem);
                }
            ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;

        }
```

And put your stack view in content view like below :

```
    <ContentView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="1" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}">
                      <StackLayout Padding="15" Spacing="10" >
                            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Item.Description}" Style="{DynamicResource LabelStyle}" YAlign="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                            <Button Text="Choose Package" Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.PackageCommand,Source={x:Reference packagePage}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Item}" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonBlue}" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                        </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: Device.RuntimePlatform==Device.Android was added only because it caused issues in iOS. Your solution is not working

Comment: See my updated answer. You should remove old item based on id in your list and add new updated item.